# How to change the index of NavBar by using a button from another Screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I'm using [CurvedNavigationBar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar/example) in the main file which has the MaterialApp and I'm using a List for the body which changes depending on the index of the clicked icon in the bar. The second item in the bar takes the user to another screen and the button called "Istoric Programari" should be doing the same, but it pushes the screen on top of the tree stack instead. I tried adding a callback function but then i have to initialize it in the List of widgets and that apparently isn't allowed.
The structure is as follows:
Main screen has HomeScreen set as default. Inside HomeScreen, DosarulMeu widget has a ListView that renders the three buttons by returning the custom widget DosarulMeuItem. The 1st button "Istoric Programari" is supposed to change the navbar to the second element.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(home: MyApp()), // use MaterialApp
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // GlobalKey<CurvedNavigationBarState> _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();
  var _page = 0;

  final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomePage(),
    ProgramariScreen(),
    TratamenteScreen(),
    LoginPage(),
    MeniuScreen(),
  ];

  List<Widget> icons = const [
    ImageIcon(AssetImage("./assets/images/navbar/home.png")),
    ImageIcon(AssetImage("./assets/images/navbar/programari.png")),
    ImageIcon(AssetImage("./assets/images/navbar/contact.png")),
    ImageIcon(AssetImage("./assets/images/navbar/educatie.png")),
    ImageIcon(AssetImage("./assets/images/navbar/menu.png")),
  ];

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: curvedNavigation(),
      body: pages[_page],
    );
  }

  CurvedNavigationBar curvedNavigation() {
    return CurvedNavigationBar(
      onTap: changePage,
      animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 236, 236),
      buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      color: Colors.white,
      items: icons,
      height: 60,
      index: 0,
    );
  }

  void changePage(index) {
    setState(
      () {
        _page = index;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
Padding dosarulMeu(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Container(
        height: 250,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 25, 10, 0),
                child: IntrinsicWidth(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Dosarul meu',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                        physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: dosarulMeuList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return DosarulMeuItem(
                            titlu: dosarulMeuList[index].titlu,
                            widgetRoute: dosarulMeuList[index].widgetRoute,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Image.asset('./assets/images/dentist.png',
                      height: 130, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4))
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DosarulMeuItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String titlu;
  final Widget widgetRoute;

  const DosarulMeuItem({
    required this.titlu,
    required this.widgetRoute,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => widgetRoute),
        );
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        child: Container(
            width: 100,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 0, 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 236, 236)),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(titlu,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.red)),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below Steps :

1. ```
   GlobalKey <CurvedNavigationBarState> _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();  // Set Globally outside Class
   ```
2. ```
   CurvedNavigationBar(
      key: _bottomNavigationKey,
      ... 
      )
   ```
3. ```
   ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: (){ _bottomNavigationKey.currentState!.setPage(1); }, // Set index of your choice  
      ),
   ```

Follow the documentation : https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've considered using the GlobalKey but I did not find any example on how to pass it to another screen in order to make any use of it.

Comment: yoy can use constructor function or state management tool like GetX, Provider